# Google Adwords conversion on form submission in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I would like to have a Google Adwords conversion trigger when a *new* node is submitted on my Drupal 6 site, but cannot find a way to do this.

Basically I want a user to submit some details into a custom node type, let's call it "Player". When a new Player is added, I want to trigger an Adwords conversion. I have looked at the [Custom (Form) Destination](http://drupal.org/project/customdestination) module, but this doesn't seem to work for this form. Even if it did work, I'd have to somehow cleverly distinguish between *new* submissions and *edits* because they have the same `form_id`.

Anyone have experience of something similar to this and can offer any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it turns out they wanted it just when someone used the contact form, so I created a webform (using [webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform) module) for my contact form and then used php code in the thankyou page to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

This is likely going to take a small bit of coding in a custom module.

I would recommend creating a hook_node implementation which fires when a node is being created. It then fires off the adwords conversion.

Something like:

```
function mymodule_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $a3 = NULL, $a4 = NULL) {
  if ($op == 'insert' && $node->type == 'whatever_content_type') {
    // Code to trigger adwords conversion.
  }
}
```

If you need help creating a custom module, I would suggest you visit the Drupal Development IRC Chatroom at #drupal on irc.freenode.net. Someone there would be happy to help you get started!

Comment: Thankss BrianV... I may well appear there soon :)